# Running an Autohotkey timer script when computer was off at scheduled time

Tags: autohotkey, timer

The below script  opens a file at a specific time via AHK. If the computer is off at that time, what should be the way to run this script ?

```
 #Persistent

SetTimer, CheckTime, 5000
Return

CheckTime:
TheTime = %A_Hour%%A_Min%
If (TheTime = 1525) && !(Ran)
{
    Run, C:\Test.txt
    Ran := 1
}
```

Comment: You could schedule the computer to wake-up if it's asleep at the schedule time. I've done similar things by scheduling a dummy .bat file to run at desired time using the Scheduled Tasks control panel. There may be some way to do the scheduling from AHK, but I've never looked into it.

Comment: P.S. When you create a task with the Scheduled Task Wizard, there's an option to "Open advance Progrerties for this task when I click Finish" at the end. If you check it, a new dialog will open, and you can enable the "Wake the computer to run this task" option on the Settings tab within it.

Comment: Here's an [example](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/61042-create-a-scheduled-task-natively-ahk-l/?hl=%2Bschedule+%2Btask#entry608055) of creating a scheduled task from within AHK.

Comment: it has a lot of stuff. can you direct me to the proper script?

Comment: There's only one script. It's a little long because it has a GUI. Unfortunately I don't have one of the required versions Of Windows (Vista, 7, or 8) to run it myself.